# Finding If a page/request id occurs in a session or not in r using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I have this working DF :

```
lf3 = structure(list(session_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L), userId = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 14), datetime = structure(c(1457029336, 1457029337, 
1457029340, 1457029596, 1457030783, 1457030784, 1457030918, 1457030920, 
1457031472, 1457031674, 1457031675, 1457031677, 1457031678, 1457032116, 
1457032117, 1457032963, 1457032964, 1457032966, 1457032967, 1457033246, 
1457033247, 1457033249, 1457033359, 1457033530, 1457034351, 1457034353, 
1457034356, 1457034623, 1457034624, 1457035397), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), referer = c(22, 2, 6, 20, 21, 6, 23, 
17, 21, 22, 11, 10, 6, 24, 10, 6, 25, 26, 27, 8, 6, 1, 6, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 6, 30, 32), request = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 
9, 6, 10, 10, 9, 6, 11, 9, 12, 13, 8, 3, 9, 3, 14, 13, 11, 15, 
6, 6, 16)), .Names = c("session_id", "userId", "datetime", "referer", 
"request"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now i am looking for certain requests ids to match if they are in a session or not and if they do return their position index in dataframe

I am trying this code but somehow not getting any success :

```
lf3 %>% group_by(session_id) %>% do(.,match(6,.,request))
```

checking for **request=6** is in session or not and return positional index(doing foreach session)

Comment: can you please elaborate what you mean by `if they are in a session or not`

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: i just want its index position and if it exists in a session or not(TRUE or FALSE) then later i'll do sum to find out number of sessions containing that pageid/request .Suppose we check for 6 it is in many sessions with different ids and now i want to return relative index position of that element using do function but cant get success

Comment: Could you please update your post with expected answer or is there none?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will print your desired output:-

"as.numeric(rownames(lf3[ifelse(lf3$session_id==6,T,F),]))"

Answer (score 0):

This is one option:

```
lf3 %>% group_by(session_id) %>% 
                      summarise(do_match = 6 %in% request,
                      act_match = ifelse(6 %in% request,which(request==6),0))
```

Mind that a request might appear twice in a session (this captures only the first)